# Java Swing timer does not do what I want it to

Tags: java, swing, timer

I need to write a program that uses a swing countdown timer to do something (in this case, print out a String in the console). It gets the needed delay info from a spinner and executes the code when I hit the Start button. However, when I enter a value in the spinner, it just waits for twice that many seconds and finishes the run without printing out anything.

```
private void StartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      

  int x = (int) Spinner1.getValue() * 1000;
  Timer TIMER = new Timer(x, new MyActionListener());

  TIMER.start();

  try {
    Thread.sleep(x * 2);

  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
  }

  TIMER.stop();
}

class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Something");
  }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For better and sooner help, provide a [MCVE]

Comment: Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Comment: What is the nonsense with `Thread.sleep(x * 2);` supposed to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are locking out yourself.

With

```
Thread.sleep(x * 2);
```

you are blocking the EventDispatchThread that would run your ActionListener. Still the timer internally keeps a flag that the timeout occured and that it should run your ActionListener at the next possible time.

But

```
TIMER.stop();
```

is resetting the TIMER, so that the notification is lost.